# "Undownload" Images for HTML email

Tags: microsoft-outlook

By default, I have images blocked in my Outlook client. To show them, I can choose to download images for a specific email.

Let's assume this was done by mistake and I want to revert that image back to the original state, where the images are not downloaded. Is there a way to do that via the UI (or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to go to File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Automatic Download and see if the following settings are what you need.

[image]

Outlook uses the Safe Senders/Safe Recipients Lists to make decisions.  That's accessible by going here:

[image]

and then select the appropriate tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case I'm looking to do the opposite. The default options are to not download anything. For a particular email I clicked "download" and can see the images. I want to reset the state for that specific email so the images are not visible again.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you would like to "undownload" the picture that you have downloaded in your message before, is it right?

If so, I have performed some tests on my Outlook, the picture would be invisible when the message was moved to Junk Email folder, but it would display again once we move the message back. I also have tried to clear the local temp file, but it also doesn't work, it seems to the picture in message has been downloaded in your data file, and we may have no options to undownload(or delete) these pictures in Outlook.